# Firebase create a document and increment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to increment a value for my documents; Sometimes the document does not exist, so I need to create it and then update it.

```py
    my_ref = db.collection(u'my_col').document(f"my_doc_key")
    my_doc = my_ref.get()

    if my_doc.exists:
        my_ref.update({"count": firestore.Increment(1)})
    else:
        my_ref.set({"count": 1})
```

I know I can use `update()` and `Increment()` if the document exists. I know that if the document does not exist, I can create it and set a collection inside it with `set()`. Is there a way I can do this in one method? Something like this:

```py
    my_ref.set({"count": firestore.Increment(1)})
```

Comment: If you solved your question, accept the answer so that community members visiting your question can refer to the accepted answer.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra A poster can only accept their own answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using `merge=True` parameter

```py
     my_ref = db.collection(u'my_col').document(f"my_doc_key")
     my_ref.set({"count": firestore.Increment(1)}, merge=True)
```